# Return 1 or 0 in SQL depending on the multiple statements

Tags: mysql, sql

If I find that some of the user exists with such a parameters, I want to get 1 otherwise 0. In the future I'll have to add more blocks. But it doesn't seem to work now. What am I doing wrong?

```
 SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1
                              FROM Customers
                              WHERE Country = 'France' AND PostalCode%2 = 0)
                              OR (WHERE Country = 'Germany' AND PostalCode%2 = 0))
                              ) 
                  THEN 1 
                  ELSE 0 
              END AS BIT)
```

Comment: Now it differs. Sorry

Comment: `...WHERE Country = 'France' AND PostalCode%2 = 0
OR Country = 'Germany' AND PostalCode%2 = 0)`

Answer (score 2):

You need two separate `exists`:

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM Customers
                              WHERE Country = 'France' AND PostalCode%2 = 0
                             )
                 THEN 1
                 WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM Customers
                              WHERE Country = 'Germany' AND PostalCode%2 = 0
                             )
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END AS BIT)
```

Actually, I broke this into two separate `THEN` clauses.  This is almost equivalent to using `OR`, but because the logic is inside a `CASE`, `THEN` seems more natural.  (The difference is that the optimizer could choose to re-arrange the `OR` conditions, but the `THEN` conditions are executed in lexical order.)

If your statements are actually this simple, you can combine them as:

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM Customers
                              WHERE Country IN ('France', 'Germany') AND PostalCode%2 = 0
                             )
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END AS BIT)
```

Comment: I need doing it with OR. If at least one of two statements is true - then return 1.

Comment: Got It. Thanks, will try It

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're just having issues with your bracketing:

```
SELECT CAST(
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM Customers
        WHERE (Country = 'France' AND PostalCode%2 = 0)
        OR (Country = 'Germany' AND PostalCode%2 = 0)
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)
```

Building on Gordon's assumption that `PostalCode%2 = 0` for all tested 'sets' of conditionals (you haven't said as much yet), you could likewise shorten this to:

```
SELECT CAST(
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM Customers
        WHERE PostalCode%2 = 0 
        AND Country IN ('France', 'Germany')
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)
```